# How can we see change logs for events?

Tags: civievent, logging

We are using Civi 4.7.13 with logging enabled.
How can we access the logs specifically for events to see the user change history, when an event was deleted and possibly what changed?

Comment: You may need to clarify whether it is the event or the participant that is being deleted.

Comment: Thanks petednz - fuzion 3.  Currently it is the event that is being deleted. A simple solution is to limit the user permissions and instead grant the delete permissions to 1-2 people. Ideally we'd like to be able to look at logs for changes including participant changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the logs for Events via the UI. If you have access to the db then most tables have a log table, eg log_civicrm_event and log_civicrm_participant

Comment: I don't think so either. Would be a useful feature to have events logging reports similar to contacts. Thanks for the back end db tip.

Comment: for drupal users, the other option would be to make Log tables available to Views which is something i have often thought about. BTW if you agree I answered the question, can you pls +1 and 'accept'